# Proving that greedy algorithm on TSP does not produce optimal solution

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, examples-counterexamples

I know that solving a TSP requires considering all possible cycles in the graph, and that a nearest neighbor greedy algorithm does not always produce the shortest path.
I found [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/counterexamples-to-the-greedy-algorithm?newreg=0269e5c070094f0cb36b3e780148164a) answer that gives a counterexample for such a greedy algorithm, but it only consider starting from a specific vertex (A).
My question is, if we apply this greedy algorithm `n` times starting at each of the `n` vertex, why wouldn't it yields an optimal short path?
I didn't manged to come up with any counterexample yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counterexample where the optimal solution is of weight $13$ but it takes more than $100$ if we use the greedy algorithm starting from any vertex:

[image]

Comment: The TSP usually refers to a round-trip. There's no round-trip solution of weight $8$ in this graph (since there are only $7$ edges of weight $1$).

Comment: @joriki thanks for pointing out, that's a careless mistake, edited.